# System.ArgumentException: Couldn't bind to method 'GetGetDefaultCipherSuitesHandler'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am testing an app and seeing crashes on certain Android devices. The error we are seeing in the device logs (and Crashlytics):

```
Fatal Exception: android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.ArgumentException: Couldn't bind to method 'GetGetDefaultCipherSuitesHandler'.
  at System.Delegate.GetCandidateMethod (System.Type type, System.Type target, System.String method, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bflags, System.Boolean ignoreCase, System.Boolean throwOnBindFailure) [0x000f9] in <e5404a7cbaab472a85c87c8c593feada>:0 
  at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Type target, System.String method, System.Boolean ignoreCase, System.Boolean throwOnBindFailure) [0x00014] in <e5404a7cbaab472a85c87c8c593feada>:0 
  at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Type target, System.String method) [0x00000] in <e5404a7cbaab472a85c87c8c593feada>:0 
  at Android.Runtime.AndroidTypeManager.RegisterNativeMembers (Java.Interop.JniType jniType, System.Type type, System.String methods) [0x00123] in <b9d3dca3be2f48d1874313a7a497190a>:0 
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.RegisterJniNatives (System.IntPtr typeName_ptr, System.Int32 typeName_len, System.IntPtr jniClass, System.IntPtr methods_ptr, System.Int32 methods_len) [0x00115] in <b9d3dca3be2f48d1874313a7a497190a>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Java.Interop.NativeMethods.java_interop_jnienv_alloc_object(intptr,intptr&,intptr)
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+Object.AllocObject (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type) [0x00027] in <55c8950cd1f2461e9c76bad39e8fc8a4>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniType.AllocObject () [0x0000c] in <55c8950cd1f2461e9c76bad39e8fc8a4>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.StartCreateInstance (System.String constructorSignature, System.Type declaringType, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00044] in <55c8950cd1f2461e9c76bad39e8fc8a4>:0 
  at Javax.Net.Ssl.SSLSocketFactory..ctor () [0x00034] in <b9d3dca3be2f48d1874313a7a497190a>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Net.OldAndroidSSLSocketFactory..ctor () [0x00010] in <b9d3dca3be2f48d1874313a7a497190a>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler.SetupSSL (Javax.Net.Ssl.HttpsURLConnection httpsConnection) [0x00027] in <b9d3dca3be2f48d1874313a7a497190a>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler.SetupRequestInternal (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, Java.Net.URLConnection conn) [0x0007b] in <b9d3dca3be2f48d1874313a7a497190a>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00236] in <b9d3dca3be2f48d1874313a7a497190a>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncWorker (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption completionOption, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000ca] in <0029d260a26b48288c90ea4fe946b24c>:0 
  at MyObfuscatedAppName.Services.CharacterEmbeddedResourceDriver.<LoadCharacters>b__1_0 (System.IObserver`1[T] observer) [0x000ca] in <446b676d44a2438aa46540b6f67c24f8>:0 
  at System.Reactive.PlatformServices.ExceptionServicesImpl.Rethrow (System.Exception exception) [0x00006] in <9ce90c81f389405fa2d38b0e75e8871b>:0 
  at System.Reactive.ExceptionHelpers.Throw (System.Exception exception) [0x0000a] in <99f8205c51c44bb480747b577b8001ff>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Stubs+<>c.<.cctor>b__2_1 (System.Exception ex) [0x00000] in <99f8205c51c44bb480747b577b8001ff>:0 
  at System.Reactive.AnonymousSafeObserver`1[T].OnError (System.Exception error) [0x0000e] in <99f8205c51c44bb480747b577b8001ff>:0 
  at System.Reactive.Concurrency.ObserveOn`1+ObserveOnSink[TSource].OnErrorPosted (System.Object error) [0x00000] in <99f8205c51c44bb480747b577b8001ff>:0 
  at Android.App.SyncContext+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Post>b__0 () [0x00000] in <b9d3dca3be2f48d1874313a7a497190a>:0 
  at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in <b9d3dca3be2f48d1874313a7a497190a>:0 
  at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00009] in <b9d3dca3be2f48d1874313a7a497190a>:0 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.31(intptr,intptr)
       at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(RunnableImplementor.java)
       at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run(RunnableImplementor.java:30)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5479)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

It would seem that the part of this stack trace that relates to our code:

```
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncWorker (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption completionOption, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000ca] in <0029d260a26b48288c90ea4fe946b24c>:0 
  at MyObfuscatedAppName.Services.CharacterEmbeddedResourceDriver.<LoadCharacters>b__1_0 (System.IObserver`1[T] observer) [0x000ca] in <446b676d44a2438aa46540b6f67c24f8>:0
```

Is probably happening when our LoadCharacters() method begins:

```
public IObservable<CharacterJsonRoot> LoadCharacters()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("MyApp :: Load Characters");

    return Observable.Create<CharacterJsonRoot>(async observer =>
    {
        if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://myapp.obfuscated.com");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("/my/path/to/file/data.json");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Loaded from server");
                var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var characters = DeserializeJson(data);
                observer.OnNext(characters);
                observer.OnCompleted();
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Loaded from fallback");
                var assembly = typeof(CharacterEmbeddedResourceDriver).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
                var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyApp.Services.Data.data.json");

                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    string result = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                    var characters = DeserializeJson(result);
                    observer.OnNext(characters);
                    observer.OnCompleted();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // write your code if there is no Internet available  
            Debug.WriteLine("Loaded from fallback & NO  Internet available ");
                var assembly = typeof(CharacterEmbeddedResourceDriver).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
                var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyApp.Services.Data.data.json");

                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    string result = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                    var characters = DeserializeJson(result);
                    observer.OnNext(characters);
                    observer.OnCompleted();
                }
        }
    }).SubscribeOn(System.Reactive.Concurrency.TaskPoolScheduler.Default).ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current);
}
```

Other than that, I really have no idea why this error is happening only on certain devices. We are testing using App Live in Browser Stack and it always crashes for Galaxy Note 3 and Samsung Tab 4. Yet it will never crash on the Samsung Galaxy S7, for example.

**UPDATE:**
It's only happening on Android 4.4 and lower. So I've updated my Android project by setting the minimum Android version required to be 5. However, I would still like to know why this error occurs and what it means, so I'm leaving this open.

Comment: Do you know which Android SDK version of tested devices , maybe related to it.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Good point. The Android version it crashes on is 4.4 (and I would imagine anything below that). V5 and up it works fine.

Comment: Glad be helpful :)

Comment: So what is the solution then? Is there a solution to this error or do we need to prevent the app from being downloaded on devices with 4.4 or lower (if that's even possible?)

Comment: Checking **Minimun Android Version** of project's `AndroidMinifest.xml` , be sure that support 4.4 or even lower version.

Comment: Great, thanks. Done that. Meanwhile, I'll keep this open until someone can explain why the error is happening.

Comment: Okey, you may have components or libraries in your project that only work above 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue too. Turns out it was overzealous [Linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker). Adding `Mono.Android` to `Skip linking assemblies` fixed it for me.